Has multiobjective prize collecting steiner tree or TSP been studied?
Suppose we have a graph $G$ a root $r$ and each node $v$ has some amount of $c_{v,i}$ of each resource $i$.
I connect a set of nodes to the root that maximizes the minimum amount of any resource using at most a given number of edges.
Has this problem been studied?

@NealYoung Isn't just Steiner tree NP-complete?

@NealYoung  approximation algorithms mostly

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@NealYoung Yes I mean find a  connected subgraph containing the root with $k$ edges  maximizing the minimum, over all resources $i$, of the sum of $c_{vi}$. I don't assume the graph is a tree but in my case I'm assuming edges are positive so I would not ever select noncut edges.
